# Adding multiple object values to array with key names

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

In Laravel, I'm trying to create an array of some existing values I have that are built from values from a JSON object.

I have the 4 variables set and they dump properly but I'd like to add all 4 (username, perms, roles, access) to the array (IdentifierArray) with their own key/name so that when I add the array to the session and inspect it, I can see each value with it's key/name.

Code at this point:

```
$IdentifierArray = [];

$Username = $login->username;
$Perms = $login->permissions;
$Roles = $login->roles;
$Access = $login->access;

Session::put('Array of Values', $identifierArray);
```

So I'd like to add those object values to the array in the best way while having a key for each as well, like:

```
Array(
    "username": $username value,
    "perms":$perms value,
    "Roles":$roles value,
    "Access":$Access value
)
```

Comment: So, the problem is?

Comment: You don't know about `$identifierArray['key'] = 'value';`?

Comment: @u_mulder but I'm just wondering about adding the key to each of the 4 objects within the array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of doing it, equal to @danboh:

```
$IdentifierArray = [
  "username" => $login->username,
  "permissions" => $login->permissions,
  "roles" => $login->roles,
  "access" => $login->access
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a regular PHP array? Like:

```
$IdentifierArray["username"] = $login->username;
$IdentifierArray["permissions"] = $login->permissions;
$IdentifierArray["roles"] = $login->roles;
$IdentifierArray["access"] = $login->access;
```

Comment: I may do this, I just wasn't sure if there was a better way I should go about it within laravel. This should still do the job though, thanks!

Comment: In that case, take a look at the toArray() method in your collection https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-toarray

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `array_only` helper to make your life easy:

```
$identifierArray = array_only(
    json_decode($login, true), 
    ['username', 'permissions', 'roles', 'access']
);
```

Another option would be to use the `only()` Collection method:

```
collect(json_decode($login, true))
    ->only(['username', 'permissions', 'roles', 'access'])
    ->all();
```